# Evaluation of bash commands as ansible variables

Tags: ansible

I want to create ansible equivalent of the command:

```
apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Requirement: a `linux-headers-$(uname -r)` package must be configured via Ansible variable.

In external file a big list of packages is configured. Now packages, whose names are evaluated lazily like `linux-headers-$(uname -r)` must be handled via shell task individually.

I am looking for a way to get rid of such exceptions and store them in the variable list as the others.

Answer (score 1):

Use [pipe](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/pipe.html#pipe-read-output-from-a-command) plugin. For example

```
- set_fact:
    linux_headers_pkg: "{{ 'linux-headers-' ~ lookup('pipe', 'uname -r') }}"
- debug:
    var: linux_headers_pkg
```

gives

```
"linux_headers_pkg": "linux-headers-5.0.0-31-generic"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Vladimir Botka for the pipe. Here is a solution I've implemnted based on variables, `pipe` and `replace`:

The package is described in external file as:

```
---
- packages:
    - name: Some Package Description,
      package: linux-headers-${pipe}
      pipe: uname -r
```

Playbook, we get result of `pipe` and replace in the `package`:

```
- name: test pipe
  debug:
    msg: "key: {{ item.package | replace('${pipe}', lookup('pipe', item.pipe)) }}"
  when: item.pipe is defined
  with_items: "{{ packages }}"
```

Output:

> ```
> TASK [pipe] ********************************************************************
> skipping: [default] => (item={u'packageList': [u'package1,', u'package2,', u'package3'], u'name': u'Some description 1,'}) 
> ok: [default] => (item={u'pipe': u'uname -r', u'name': u'Some description 1,', u'package': u'linux-headers-${pipe}'}) => {
>     "msg": "key: linux-headers-4.15.0-65-generic"
> }
> ```