# How to evaluate nested bash expressions in ansible commands?

Tags: linux, bash, ansible

I am trying to write an ansible script, and want to run a command with nested commands, e.g.:

`echo "$(uname -s)-$(uname -r)" | grep "Linux"`

NOTE: (The actual command is a curl request with multiple pipes and substitutions, but the above is just for simplification)

In my ansible playbook:

```
    - name: Run commands
      command: "{{ item }}"
      loop:
        - ...
        - echo "$(uname -s)-$(uname -r)" | grep "Linux"
        - ....
```

The problem is, ansible does not evaluate internal expressions and runs it literally:
`changed: [<IP>] => (item=echo "$(uname -s)-$(uname -r)" | grep "Linux")`

I've seen [examples of using pipe and lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58555454/evaluation-of-bash-commands-as-ansible-variables), but can't quite replicate it for multiple nested expressions.

Thanks

Comment: [_The command(s) will not be processed through the shell, so variables like `$HOSTNAME` and operations like `"*"`, `"<"`, `">"`, `"|"`, `";"` and `"&"` will not work. Use the ansible.builtin.shell module if you need these features._](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html#synopsis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As highlighted by β.εηοιτ.βε, by using the [`shell` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-shell-module) I was able to execute the commands.

Changes code:

```
    - name: Run commands
      shell: "{{ item }}"
      loop:
        - ...
        - echo "$(uname -s)-$(uname -r)" | grep "Linux"
        - ....
```